# Calling cmd to choose a path and store it afterward

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to make a batch file that let the user choose a path to a directory and afterward, store this path in a .txt file.
I tought about calling the cmd to choose the path :

```
cd C:/
call "cmd"
```

But, is it possible to store the path the user has chosen after that the user has set the path he wants and entered something like "done" to exit the cmd and return to batch file's commands ?

I don't think it is possible; if it is, is it possible to do same thing only using the batch file's commands ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
:start
@echo off
set /p dir="Enter path: "
echo %dir% >> path.txt
set /p done="Enter another path? [y/n]: "
if %done%==y goto start
set dir=
set done=
```

Comment: Thanks, not exactly what i expected, but the principle is here, I will jam around this :D